# How to extract a specific war file to a specific folder

Tags: python, jar

I have the python code which will download the `.war` file and put it in a path which is specified by the variable `path`.

Now I wish to extract a specific file from that war to a specific folder.

But I got struck up here :

```
os.system(jar -xvf /*how to give the path varible here*/  js/pay.js)
```

I'm not sure how to pass on the variable `path` to `os.system` command.

I'm very new to python, kindly help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use `os.system`, the shell command line is passed as a string, and you can pass any string you want. So:

```
os.system('jar -xvf "' + pathvariable + '" js/pay.js)
```

Or you can use `{}` or `%s` formatting, etc.

However, you probably do not want to use `os.system`.

First, if you want to run other programs, it's almost always better to use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. For example:

```
subprocess.check_call(['jar', '-xvf', pathvariable, 'js/pay.js'])
```

As you can see, you can pass a list of arguments instead of trying to work out how to put a string together (and deal with escaping and quoting and all that mess). And there are lots of other advantages, mostly described in the documentation itself.

However, you probably don't want to run the `war` tool at all. As jimhark says, a [WAR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29) is just a special kind of [JAR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29), which is just a special kind of [ZIP file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_file_format). For creating them, you generally want to use JAR/WAR-specific tools (you need to verify the layout, make sure the manifest is the first entry in the ZIP directory, take care of the package signature, etc.), but for expanding them, any ZIP tool will work. And Python has ZIP support built in. What you want to do is probably as simple as this:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(pathvariable, 'r') as zf:
    zf.extract('js/pay.js', destinationpathvariable)
```

IIRC, you can only directly use `ZipFile` in a `with` statement in 2.7 and 3.2+, so if you're on, say, 2.6 or 3.1, you have to do it indirectly:

```
from contextlib import closing
import zipfile
with closing(zipfile.ZipFile(pathvariable, 'r')) as zf:
    zf.extract('js/pay.js', destinationpathvariable)
```

Or, if this is just a quick&dirty script that quits as soon as it's done, you can get away with:

```
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(pathvariable, 'r')
zf.extract('js/pay.js', destinationpathvariable)
```

But I try to always use `with` statements whenever possible, because it's a good habit to have.

Comment: I'm getting an error as `NameError: name 'ZipFile' is not defined`

Comment: `import zipfile` first. Then `zipfile.ZipFile(pathvariable, 'r')...`. It might depend on your python version, but just read the docs and you'll see.

Comment: Sorry for the typo; thanks to @MattiasNilsson for correcting it. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't a `war` file a type of `zip` file? Python has [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) support (click link for docs page).

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.environ, it holds all environment variables on it.
It is a dict, so you can just use it like:

```
pypath = os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
```

now if you mean it's a common python variable, just use it like:

```
var1 = 'pause'
os.system('@echo & %s' % var1)
```